# Soyatec eUML2 free edition cannot create a project for it in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I installed Soyatec free edition in Eclipse Helios. But in the Eclipse Project Wizard, I cannot find a way to create a Soyatec UML type project. I think its Studio edition made an entry in Eclipse projec wizard. Any idea how to create a project for Soyatec free edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Right click on project folder.
2. select: New->Other
3. In the wizard select eUML2 Free Edition Diagram and choose the desired diagram

Comment: It looks like free edition is only for existing project. It will not allow you to create a UML project without reference to an existing project. It will not create a class diagram or sequenece diagram. If you want to start from nothing and want to draw some class diagrams before you jump to code, you cannot do it with free edition. So free edition is to make you mad and then buy the studio edtion.

Comment: create an empty java project, create an uml class diagram like desrcribed in my answer, open the diagram e start adding class. it works.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped this tool because it changed my java code and added plenty of @uml tags in my code.

I had a big project that I wanted to reverse and get class diagrams.
I got some diagrams but my code was totally changed without my permission. It was such a mess that I had to erase my project. The problem was that I was working on CVS and did not realize at the beginning that my code was changed. I therefore commited my change when closing my laptop. It is only tomorrow that all the others developers on the projects noticed over 1 000 changes. All our CVS installation was corrupted after.
What a mess !!

I can only recommend this tool to my worst enemies :-)

Comment: what do you recommend to your firends?

Comment: If a beginner then UMLet is the solution. This is a drawing tool creating UML diagrams. Really easy to use. UMLet limitation is no reverse engineering, no model, no team work but a really easy drawing tool. A kind of Powerpoint. If you need a model, reverse etc..... then RSA IBM is the best. If Java then the best is Omondo. Both tools are not free but really excellent and a good investment if team works.